# How to deal with Exceptions in C++ programming when there are a lot of memory allocation

Tags: c++, exception

I am a novice in the field of C++ program and I read the book More Effective C++. There is one specific section about how to deal with C++ exceptions. In terms of the item 10, the author claims that we should avoid the memory leak in the constructors as the following example.

```
BookEntry::BookEntry(const string& name, const string& address, 
                    const string& imageFileName, 
                    const string& audioClipFileNmae):theName(name), theAddress(address), 
                    theImage(0), theAudioClip(0) {
    try {
        if (imageFileName != "") {
            theImage = new Image(imageFileName);
        }
        if (audioClipFileName != "") {
            theAudioClip = new AudioClip(audioClipFileName);
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        delete theImage;
        delete theAudioClip;
   }
```

In this way, we can avoid the source leak when there is an error of creating theImage or theAudioClip. My question is that if there is a lot of functions which contains memory allocation as the following.

```
void BookEntry::test1() {
    float *A = new float[1000];
    float *B = new float[1000];

    ....
    delete [] A;
    delete [] B;
}
```

Do I have to use the try catch structure to deal with the danger of memory leak? Usually, I prefer to just testing whether the pointer A and pointer B are null pointer or not and if the allocation fail, I will abort the program immediately.

Comment: The book is somewhat outdated. Today you use smart pointers for automatic exception safety.

Comment: @n.m. What you pointed is one way to solve the memory leak problem. However, the smart pointer cannot contain an array. What should I do to deal with this situation?

Comment: "one way to solve the memory leak problem" No, this is **the** way to solve the resource management problem. "the smart pointer cannot contain an array" First, a smart pointer can point to a vector just fine. Second, most of your array needs are answered by `std::vector`.

Comment: @n.m. I believe that there is no need for me to use a smart pointer to point to a vector. The std::vector will release its own resources. I just wonder how we can deal with the raw array. Sometimes, I prefer to use raw array due to some special reasons. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I mean a smart pointer can point to a *raw array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably misunderstanding what the book meant by "memory leak". A failure to allocate may be the eventual *result* of a memory leak, but the two things are not the same.

What the book is talking about is what happens if `AudioClip`s constructor fails. Not the memory allocation of `AudioClip`, but `AudioClip`'s *constructor*. Because remember, constructors only have one way to signal failure: throwing an exception.

If it throws, and someone in the call stack of your `BookEntry` constructor invocation catches that exception, then the previously allocated `theImage` will *never* be cleaned up. `BookEntry`'s constructor never successfully completed, so its destructor will never be called (since the object never existed, you can't delete it).

This is why nowadays (aka: post-C++11), we would store those allocated members in smart pointers. While `BookEntry`'s destructor will never be called, the destructors for any of its successfully constructed subobjects *will* be called. So if `theImage` is a `unique_ptr<Image>`, its destructor will be called, which will delete the `Image` it holds.

> Usually, I prefer to just testing whether the pointer A and pointer B are null pointer or not and if the allocation fail, I will abort the program immediately.

Then exceptions for memory allocation failure are even better for you, since you don't have to test for anything. You just let the allocation failure exception reach `main`, and your program will terminate.

However, the above issue is not about allocation failure exceptions.

Comment: I exactly agree with you. One more question please, if I failed to allocate memory and the program directly abort before the delete []A and delete B[], there will be memory leak, right? Should I take this case into consideration?

Comment: @Sean: If your program aborts, memory leaks become irrelevant, since the OS will clean up your process's memory. Now, you might have a *resource* leak, in that some global OS resource somewhere that used a destructor to close it might not get closed, but OS's usually clean those up too.

Comment: I agree with you and the operating system can help me deal with the memory leaks. So in such case, the programmer should not worry about that we have to release the memory manually. Is that right?

Comment: @Sean: But since the book is not talking about that case, it's kind of irrelevant to the point its making.